# ajax always fails on android via self-signed SSL

Tags: android, ajax, ssl

I'm fetching some string to be shown on the page via ajax and keep on getting error result:

```
$.ajax({
url : '/myurl',
data : post_param,
dataType : 'json',
type : 'POST',
success : function(data) {
    //show data on the page
}
error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
console.log(XMLHttpRequest.text);
console.log(textStatus);
console.log(errorThrown);
}
});
```

In the console log,
 
 XMLHttpRequest.text : undefined,
 
 textStatus : error,
 
 errorThrown : , (Just an empty string I think)

JQuery : 1.8.2
Android : 2.3
By the way, the ajax request is sent via self-signed SSL and there are Unicode charactors in the POST parameter which may cause the problem.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: the code above works fine with iOS, and I'm gonna give it a try on Android 4

Comment: well, some further debug info : XMLHttpRequest.readyState & state are both 0.